# How do I upload fileData for React Native using axios

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, axios

So I tried sending data to the backend without success. I am successfully communicating with the backend but I am getting the response `Required request part 'file' is not present`. I have looked at for examples online and I believe my currently implementation is correct. I could use an extra pair of eyes. Here is the code:

```
    const formData = new FormData()

    formData.append('request', {
        policyNumber: policyDetailData.policyNumber,
        documentDescription: policyDetailData.name,
        productCategory: policyDetailData.productCategory
    })
    // formData.append('file', file.fileCopyUri)
    formData.append('file', {
        uri: file.fileCopyUri,
        type: file.type,
        name: file.name
    })

    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: "post",
        url: "/documents/upload",
        responseType: "json",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        data: formData,
    };

    return await axiosInstance.request(config)
```

Am I missing anything?